# PHP SOAP Wrong Version but return response

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have a problem that a few days my service returns an

```
[faultstring] => Wrong Version
[faultcode] => VersionMismatch
```

but also returns and response.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $wsdl = "..?wsdl";
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('location' => $URL, 'trace' => 1) );

    try {
        $req = array("GetTime" =>
                    // my request
                );

        $data = $client->__soapCall("GetTime", $req);
        $result = json_decode(json_encode($data), true);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "<pre>";
            print_r($client->__getLastResponse());
        echo "</pre>";

    }
?>
```

I try with soap_version' => SOAP_1_1 and soap_version' => SOAP_1_2 but without success.

The strangest is however I'm getting response from the service with "$client->__getLastResponse()".

Does anyone have any idea where it came from this problem? I would be grateful if some an idea how to deal with the problem.

Comment: You haven't told us enough to point at a specific issue, but there being a  value in getLastResponse() is not surprising to me. Could you post the actual content of $data (before you try to en/decode it)? You could also try monitoring the actual request/response on the wire (e.g. wireshark).

Comment: @rivimey I $data is simple array with 2-3 parameters. I thinks the problem is not the $data.

Comment: then you need to tell us more of what you know...  though if $data looks ok then your json_encode/decode construction must be the problem?? perhaps pull that line out of the try/catch.